# Why production module not showing on ignition 8.0?

Tags: ignition, scada-ignition

I have recently installed ignition 8.0 with demo version. In this software, I am not able to see production module under the project browser. Any idea how to enable this module.

Regards,
Dhamu

Comment: Dhamu, are you looking for a Project called Production? Maybe a Module called Perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Ignition 8.0 does not contain a Module called Production. The core Modules are SQL Bridge, Perspective, Vision, Tag Historian, Reporting, OPC UA, Alarm Notification, SMS Notification, Sequential Function Charts, WebDev and Enterprise Administration. There are advanced Modules as well that I did not list. To view the installed Modules for your demo; login into the Ignition Gateway, navigate to the Configure tab and then choose Modules on the left pane under System. There one will see the License and state of each Module installed. You will have to reset your demo trial every two hours for the Modules to work.
Ignition’s site gives a good overview of Modules: https://docs.inductiveautomation.com/display/DOC80/Introducing+Modules

In addition, you alluded to Production and Project. If you are looking for a Project on the Gateway. You will need to Import the Production Project to the demo Gateway. Here is a link incase you are asking that question: https://docs.inductiveautomation.com/display/DOC80/Project+Export+and+Import

Please change your question if so, see comment above.